# Is this a genuinely new proof of Wallis' Product?

Tags: reference-request, infinite-product

[This (reputable) Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8GPy_UMV-08) claims to have found a new proof for Wallis' Product $$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{2n}{2n-1}\cdot \frac{2n}{2n+1}\right) = \frac{\pi}{2}.$$

There is a supplementary blog post located [here](https://www.3blue1brown.com/sridhars-corner/2018/4/17/wallis-product-supplement-dominated-convergence) that provides some detail and supplemental rigour.

The general gist of the argument is that we consider the $n$th roots of unity, along with two points on the unit circle. We then take a product of their distances to the roots of unity and use Vieta's formula to get a closed form for the products.

---

Is this a genuinely new proof for Wallis' Product? Is it completely rigorous? If not, do you know of any existing literature that outlines a similar proof?

I personally enjoyed their exhibition of the proof and think it's great that the channel is able to push maths into a more mainstream audience, I'm mainly asking this out of curiosity. Feel free to add/replace the tags with more appropriate ones.

Comment: I am aware of a proof of the uniform convergence of the Weierstrass product for the sine function over compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$, through Chebyshev polynomials of the second kind (it is in my notes, too). Since Wallis' product is just a consequence of the evaluation of such product at a specific point, and Chebyshev polynomials are fairly related to cyclotomic polynomials, I do not believe such idea is really *new*.

Answer (score 7):

**Mostly no.**

Using this sort of geometric idea to prove identities appears in [this paper by Wästlund](http://www.math.chalmers.se/~wastlund/Cosmic.pdf), where a similar construction is used to prove $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$, and more generally
$$ \pi^2\csc^2{\pi x} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(x-n)^2}. $$
On the other hand, Nick Lord ([Math. Gaz. 100, No. 549, pp. 429-434 (2016)](https://doi.org/10.1017/mag.2016.107)) suggests that the algebraic version of this proof goes back to Cauchy, at least. We will see that this proof is analogous.

---

Having skimmed the video (the author apparently not having the good grace to *write the proof down*), it seems pretty clear that the proof is a geometric analogue of the following elementary proof by Yaglom and Yaglom in 1953 (A. M. Yaglom, I. M. Yaglom, “An elementary derivation of the formulas of Wallis, Leibnitz [*sic*] and Euler for the number $\pi$”, Uspekhi Mat. Nauk, 8:5(57) (1953), pp. 181–187. Available [here](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=rm&paperid=8256&option_lang=eng). The same proof is detailed in their book "Challenging Mathematical Problems with Elementary Solutions", Problem 141 ff.)

We can prove by elementary polynomial algebra that
$$ \sin^2{\frac{2\pi}{4m}}\sin^2{\frac{4\pi}{4m}}\sin^2{\frac{6\pi}{4m}} \dotsm \sin^2{\frac{(2m-2)\pi}{4m}} = \frac{m}{2^{2m-2}} \\
\sin^2{\frac{\pi}{4m}}\sin^2{\frac{3\pi}{4m}}\sin^2{\frac{5\pi}{4m}} \dotsm \sin^2{\frac{(2m-1)\pi}{4m}} = \frac{1}{2^{2m-1}} $$
(this is done in the paper, but is fairly well-known).
We then use these to show that
$$ \frac{\sin^2{\frac{2\pi}{4m}}}{\sin^2{\frac{\pi}{4m}}} \frac{\sin^2{\frac{2\pi}{4m}}}{\sin^2{\frac{3\pi}{4m}}} \frac{\sin^2{\frac{4\pi}{4m}}}{\sin^2{\frac{3\pi}{4m}}} \frac{\sin^2{\frac{4\pi}{4m}}}{\sin^2{\frac{5\pi}{4m}}} \dotsm \frac{\sin^2{\frac{(2m-2)\pi}{4m}}}{\sin^2{\frac{(2m-3)\pi}{4m}}} \frac{\sin^2{\frac{(2m-2)\pi}{4m}}}{\sin^2{\frac{(2m-1)\pi}{4m}}} = m\sin{\frac{\pi}{2m}} $$
and
$$ \frac{\sin^2{\frac{2\pi}{4m}}}{\sin^2{\frac{3\pi}{4m}}} \frac{\sin^2{\frac{4\pi}{4m}}}{\sin^2{\frac{3\pi}{4m}}} \frac{\sin^2{\frac{4\pi}{4m}}}{\sin^2{\frac{5\pi}{4m}}} \frac{\sin^2{\frac{6\pi}{4m}}}{\sin^2{\frac{5\pi}{4m}}} \dotsm \frac{\sin^2{\frac{(2m-2)\pi}{4m}}}{\sin^2{\frac{(2m-1)\pi}{4m}}} \frac{\sin^2{\frac{2m\pi}{4m}}}{\sin^2{\frac{(2m-1)\pi}{4m}}}  = m\tan{\frac{\pi}{4m}}. $$
Obviously what happens now is a sandwiching argument: we have the trigonometric identity
$$ \frac{\sin{(k-1)a}}{\sin{ka}}\frac{\sin{(k+1)a}}{\sin{ka}} = 1-\left( \frac{\sin{a}}{\sin{ka}} \right)^2, $$
and the corresponding algebraic identity
$$ \frac{(k-1)a}{ka} \frac{(k+1)a}{ka} = 1- \left( \frac{a}{ka} \right)^2. $$
Lastly, $\sin{x}/x$ is decreasing for $0<x<\pi/2$, so in this range
$$ \frac{\sin{a}}{\sin{ka}} > \frac{a}{ka}, $$
and so
$$ \frac{\sin{(k-1)a}}{\sin{ka}}\frac{\sin{(k+1)a}}{\sin{ka}} < \frac{(k-1)a}{ka} \frac{(k+1)a}{ka}. $$
This, combined with the big products, gives us the two inequalities
$$ \frac{\frac{2\pi}{4m}}{\frac{\pi}{4m}} \frac{\frac{2\pi}{4m}}{\frac{3\pi}{4m}} \frac{\frac{4\pi}{4m}}{\frac{3\pi}{4m}} \frac{\frac{4\pi}{4m}}{\frac{5\pi}{4m}} \dotsm \frac{\frac{(2m-2)\pi}{4m}}{\frac{(2m-3)\pi}{4m}} \frac{\frac{(2m-2)\pi}{4m}}{\frac{(2m-1)\pi}{4m}} < m\sin{\frac{\pi}{2m}} \\
\frac{\frac{2\pi}{4m}}{\frac{3\pi}{4m}} \frac{\frac{4\pi}{4m}}{\frac{3\pi}{4m}} \frac{\frac{4\pi}{4m}}{\frac{5\pi}{4m}} \frac{\frac{6\pi}{4m}}{\frac{5\pi}{4m}} \dotsm \frac{\frac{(2m-2)\pi}{4m}}{\frac{(2m-1)\pi}{4m}} \frac{\frac{2m\pi}{4m}}{\frac{(2m-1)\pi}{4m}} > m\tan{\frac{\pi}{4m}}. $$
Cancelling and rearranging, this gives
$$ \frac{\pi}{2} \frac{\sin{\frac{\pi}{2m}}}{\frac{\pi}{2m}} > \frac{2}{1} \frac{2}{3} \frac{4}{3} \frac{4}{5} \dotsm \frac{2m-2}{2m-3} \frac{2m-2}{2m-1} > \frac{\pi}{2} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{2m} \right) \frac{\tan{\frac{\pi}{4m}}}{\frac{\pi}{4m}}, $$
and sending $m \to \infty$ gives the result.

The proof in the video therefore appears to be a Wästlund-esque geometric presentation of this proof, skipping over a lot of the rigour (in particular, the lengths of the chords are obviously closely related to the $\sin{(k\pi/4m)}$ in the Yagloms' proof). Indeed, this makes perfect sense, given that the Youtube channel also has a video about Wästlund's construction.

---

(Also of interest: Wästlund has another, different geometric proof of the Wallis product, using a subdivision of the area of the circle, in the American Mathematical Monthly (AMM 114, pp. 914–917 (2007)), available [here](http://www.math.chalmers.se/~wastlund/monthly.pdf).)

Comment: +1 for the detailed answer.